# How to disable all breakpoints in Xcode

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Is there an easy way to disable all breakpoints in Xcode? I tried:

- highlight all breakpoints
- click 'Deactivate'

That does not disable all of them. I need to select one at a time, and unmark the checkbox. I wonder if there is an easy way to disable a bunch of them altogether.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you expand the `Breakpoints` section in the `Groups & Files` pane, you'll find two further subdirectories - `Project Breakpoints` and `Global Breakpoints`. Assuming that the breakpoints set are specific to your current project, your breakpoints will be listed under `Project Breakpoints`. Right click on this directory and select `Disable Breakpoints` from the context menu, which will disable all the breakpoints for your project.

Comment: Where can I find the Breakpoints section in the Groups & Files pane?  I have no such section.

Answer (score 33):

With <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> you can enable or disable all of them.
With <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> you can actually see all of them.

In the previous Xcode versions,it is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

Other useful shortcuts:

http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.pdf
https://web.archive.org/web/20120518183100/https://pragmaticstudio.com/media/Xcode4Shortcuts.pdf

Comment: With ⌘+Y you can enable or disable all of them. (y) works perfectly xcode 6.1

Comment: With ⌘+Y you only activate/deactivate the breakpoints which is different than enable/disable the break points.

Comment: @koira, If you want to enable/disable them (in the way you mention), you can just go to Breakpoint navigator > select breakpoints you are interested on > right click > Enable/Disable Breakpoints. However, I reckon that if what you want is to enable/disable all of your breakpoints, why not just activate/deactivate the Breakpoint functionality? at the practical level, I feel like it has the same effect. Hope this helped.

Comment: Currently with XCode 12.2, it's Cmd + 8 to see all of the breakpoints.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 10

> The most easiest way is to do ⌘ + y to disable enable breakpoints .

There is another way

> go to Xcode project navigations pane
>
> Click on show Breakpoint navigator

[image]

> Right click on the project file and select disable all break points

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Useful shortcut is "command y" to disable all the break point. You can toggle this command to disable/enable all breakpoints. This is for Xcode 4.x version.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

From xcode 5.0 you can enable or disable all breakpoints in this fashion

Answer (score 1):

- `Xcode`->`Show the Breakpoints navigator` -> select your project -> right click -> `Disable Breakpoints`

  - [image: Disable Breakpoints]

Note:

- `Disable Breakpoints` will destroy previous status of all breakpoints

  - eg: previous status is: breakpoint 1 `enabled`, but breakpoint 2 `disabled`, after `Disable Breakpoints` then `Enable Breakpoints`, breakpoint 1 and 2 will be **enabled**

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta select 'em on the left under "Groups and files" (there should be a Breakpoints entry in the tree). Then you can right click and enable/disable from there. More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/conceptual/XcodeDebugging/500-Managing_Program_Execution/program_execution.html).