# super.viewDidLoad() crashes my app

Tags: ios, xcode

On the line where super.viewDidLoad() it says Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.1.In the console it just says "(11db)".This is a screen shot:[image]

Comment: That's a breakpoint, it's not a crash. Click on it and delete it & see if your app completes execution.

Comment: Then what do I do?

Comment: CMD-Y to disable all breakpoints

Comment: Then why does my app not load?

Comment: If it is not a crash?

Comment: I did CMD-Y and the breakpoint at super.viewdidload stayed there

Comment: There is nothing useful in that screenshot to debug a crash. Instead, post the error message printed when it crashed and any relevant code in the method that is crashing.

Comment: Where do I find the error message?

Comment: Check this to disable all breakpoints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067689/how-to-disable-all-breakpoints-in-xcode . Your application will never load if you have breakpoints everywhere and don't know how to disable them.

Comment: I pressed command y and my app still doesn't load

Comment: I still have the same old breakpoint

Comment: Then try any of the other 10 ways to disable the breakpoints. There are more ways to disable them. Just click the link and read up.

Comment: Finally!!!, thanks man. :)

Comment: Tell us which one you used to fix your issue. Maybe you can help someone else that is stuck in your situation.

Comment: I used the one where you press the pentagon thing at the bottom(where the console is) to make it turn grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was overcome by disabling all the breakpoints by pressing the arrow (pentagon thingy) at the bar near the console.

The answer was found using the answer of Abhilash Reddy in:

[How to disable all breakpoints in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067689/how-to-disable-all-breakpoints-in-xcode)